# Angular9: Type 'Observable<HttpEvent<class>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<class>'

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular9, angular-cli-v9

In my angular application, I have a service file that makes API calls. in one of the function I have as below.

```
 getSelectedPractitionerPermissions(id): Observable<classA> {
    const url =  apiUrl
    this.options = this.authService.getAuthInfo();
    return this.http.get<classA>(url, this.options);
  }
```

But I am getting an error as below

Type 'Observable<HttpEvent>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
Type 'HttpEvent' is not assignable to type 'ClassA'.
Type 'HttpSentEvent' has no properties in common with type 'ClassA'.

I have all the required headers and token I get from getAutInfo

```
  getAuthInfo() {
    const bearerToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
    let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + bearerToken);
    headers = headers.append('Cache-control', 'no-cache');
    headers = headers.append('Cache-control', 'no-store');
    headers = headers.append('Expires', 'Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT');
    headers = headers.append('Pragma', 'no-cache');
    return { headers };
  }
```

If I remove the this.options in the GET route, it works fine. But I wanted to have them as I need to pass token and other parameters.

Comment: Are you getting a runtime error or compile error?

Comment: @Damith compile time error

Comment: Try this return this.http.get<classA>(url, {headers: this.options })

Comment: @Damith If I try that, the error is gone, but the headers are not passed in the API call

Comment: This is how I used to get headers. `private getAuthInfo() {
const bearerToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
        const headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + bearerToken);
        headers.append('Cache-control', 'no-cache');
        headers.append('Cache-control', 'no-store');
        headers.append('Expires', 'Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT');
        headers.append('Pragma', 'no-cache');
        return headers;
    }`

Comment: Show us your browser request

Comment: What's `this.http`? Is it the `HttpClient` from `@angular/common/http`, or is it something else?

Comment: @mbojko yes its from @angular/common/http

Comment: @Damith The browser request is something that looks common with no headers now because of the change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **getSelectedPractitionerPermissions**

```
return this.http.get<classA>(url, {headers: this.options });
```

and in **getAuthInfo**:

```
return headers;
```

Comment: If I do that, the headers are not passed in the API call

Comment: Here is a StackBlitz to proof the behavior: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sch1gj  . Please try out. The headers are passed in the call.